# How to make a div in a vue component take up the entire screen when using position absolute?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, position

my web app is made in Vue so of course things are split up into components.

So as you can see here, Inside my ***router-view***, when I show a popup that I want to take up the entire screen, it only takes up part of it as the ***nav bar*** is rendered and that takes up 10vh.

***You can see it here:***

[image]

So I know there is one way of fixing it:

1. Move the popup div to the App.vue file and use $emit to tell it to show when the button is pressed. Since it is in the App.vue file, it will take up 100vh.

**However I'm wondering if there is anything easier I can do to simply make the div take up the full screen, even though it's in the router view and not at the top level?**

Code example (the overlay and one of the list items):

```
 <!-- MOBILE MORE INFO POP UP OVERLAY -->
    <transition name="fade" mode="out-in">
      <div class="mobile-popup-overlay" v-if="currentService != '' && $mq === 'sm'"></div>
    </transition>
    <!-- MOBILE MORE INFO POP UP -->
    <!-- COVID POPUP -->
    <transition name="fade" mode="out-in">
      <div class="popup-item" v-if="currentService === 'COVID-19' && $mq === 'sm'">
        <div class="popup-item__wrapper" :class="$mq">
          <div class="popup-item__icon-container new-service" :class="$mq">
            <i class="fas fa-shield-virus icon" :class="$mq"></i>
          </div>
          <div class="popup-item__description" :class="$mq">
            <h3 :class="$mq">COVID-19 Security</h3>
            <h4 class="new-service__p">NEW SERVICE</h4>
            <p>
              <b>COVID-19 Temperature Screening System</b>
            </p>
            <button class="tag-btn-blue-full" :class="$mq">Enquire</button>
            <button class="tag-btn-green-secondary" :class="$mq">More Info</button>
            <button class="popup-item__description__mobile-button" @click="changeService('close')">
              <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </transition>
```

The overlays current css:

```
.mobile-popup-overlay {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: $black;
  opacity: 0.9;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  overflow: visible;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The popup might be 100vh height, but is it also at the top?
You should set the top and left property aswell:

```
top: 0;
left: 0;
```

Comment: Cant believe I didnt try this. I just assumed it was top: 0 left: 0 by default. So simple. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Elements are not really "limited" to de border of theys parents.
You can indert an element in a parent smaller than it, and i will overflow at the right and bottom.
You can use negative margin to make them overflow they parent on the top of the left.

```css
#inside {
  position: fixed;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  border : 4px solid red;
  margin : -100px 0 0 -100px
}

#container {
  height : 800px;
  width : 100px;
  border : 4px solid black;
  margin : 100px 0px 0px 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
<div id="inside">
</div>
</div>
```